# R use if else statement depending upon column number

Tags: r, shiny, plotly, r-plotly

I have a line chart that has the upper and lower confidence levels of the specific day of week, upper and lower confidence levels of weekdays if it is a weekday and weekends if it is a weekend, yesterdays count per hour, and the day before yesterdays counts per hour.  I only want the day before yesterdays counts per hour if the day is not Monday or Saturday because this line is not relevant to the line chart.  I have an if else statement and it works displaying the graph just fine but gives me an error:

> }
>   Error: unexpected '}' in "}"

I would really like to fix the code because I know that this may and probably will cause issues when I put it into my Shiny App.  This is the code:

```
if ncol(yesterday_line_chart) == 6 {

plot_ly(yesterday_line_chart, x = ~hour) %>%
    add_trace(y = ~yesterday, name = 'yesterday', mode = 'lines', line = list(color = 'rgb(205, 12, 24)', width = 3)) %>%
    add_trace(y = ~X95_up_conf_dow, name = 'dow upper conf', line = list(color = 'rgb(77, 201, 0)', width = 4, dash = 'dot')) %>%
    add_trace(y = ~X95_low_conf_dow, name = 'dow lower conf', line = list(color = 'rgb(77, 201, 0)', width = 4, dash = 'dot')) %>%
    add_trace(y = ~X95_up_conf_wd_we, name = 'we/wd upper conf', line = list(color = 'rgb(126, 142, 197)', width = 4, dash = 'dot')) %>%
    add_trace(y = ~X95_low_conf_wd_we, name = 'we/wd lower conf', line = list(color = 'rgb(126, 142, 197)', width = 4, dash = 'dot')) %>%
    layout(title = "Title",
       xaxis = list(title = "Time"),
       yaxis = list (title = "(count)")) 
}

else {

plot_ly(yesterday_line_chart, x = ~hour) %>%
    add_trace(y = ~yesterday, name = 'yesterday', mode = 'lines', line = list(color = 'rgb(205, 12, 24)', width = 3)) %>%
    add_trace(y = ~day_bef_yest, name = 'day bef yest',mode = 'lines+markers') %>%
    add_trace(y = ~X95_up_conf_dow, name = 'dow upper conf', line = list(color = 'rgb(77, 201, 0)', width = 4, dash = 'dot')) %>%
    add_trace(y = ~X95_low_conf_dow, name = 'dow lower conf', line = list(color = 'rgb(77, 201, 0)', width = 4, dash = 'dot')) %>%
    add_trace(y = ~X95_up_conf_wd_we, name = 'we/wd upper conf', line = list(color = 'rgb(126, 142, 197)', width = 4, dash = 'dot')) %>%
    add_trace(y = ~X95_low_conf_wd_we, name = 'we/wd lower conf', line = list(color = 'rgb(126, 142, 197)', width = 4, dash = 'dot')) %>%
    layout(title = "Title",
       xaxis = list(title = "Time"),
       yaxis = list (title = "(count)")) 
}
```

The python code before I use it in R conditionally removes that column(day_before_yesterday) if it is a Mon or Sat, so in R this code checks to see if there are 6 columns plot the first line graph otherwise plot the other that has 7 columns.  I have looked around and have seen a few ways to to conditionally plot but non of them keep the aesthetics that I want.

Comment: Just `if (ncol(yesterday_line_chart) == 6) {}`

Comment: Also, the `else` needs to be on the same line as the closing `}` for the if statement

Comment: Thank you @TheBiro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the problem but R seems to have different `if else` rules than most other languages..
Try taking out the `else` and instead have:
`if(ncol(yesterday_line_chart) ==7)`
and see if that helps..

Also another thing that I noticed is that you don't have brackets around your if statement which I think is necessary.

Comment: no problem! which one worked for you? Or was it both?

Comment: I tried the brackets by itself and the else statement on same line but it only worked when I changed both @Hiba Shaban    No more errors!

Comment: great! glad I could help